# Javascript function works with FF and Chrome, but not uncle Bill's browser 

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have the following function, which I use (admitedly, as a hack, since I still havent understood javascript's bizzare variable scoping rules), to fetch all global variables with a known prefix, from within a script.

The function works well with FF and Google Chrome (presumbaly it would work with all Moz derivative browsers). However, I just tested it in IE8 (aka Uncle Bill [as in Bill Gates] browser), and (perhaps unsuprisingly), the function did not work. I debugged the function and it appears that global variables are stored in another object (I could be wrong, I've only been reading on JS for a couple of days now). In any case, here is the function, which works correctly in 'Moz bazed browsers:

```
function getGlobalProperties(prefix) {
  var keyValues = [], global = window; // window for browser environments
  for (var prop in global) {
    if (prop.indexOf(prefix) == 0) // check the prefix
      keyValues.push(prop + "=" + global[prop]);
  }
  return keyValues.join('&'); // build the string
}
```

Do I need a conditional branch (and a test to see if running under IE)?

Comment: For the record, chrome is not a "mozilla derivative".  Mozilla browsers use an engine called gecko, while chrome and safari use webkit.

Comment: @Joel: the rendering engine is not important to the question, the JS engine is (which would be TraceMonkey in current Firefox builds and V8 in Chrome)

Comment: in which IE version does it fail - seems to work on my IE8.0.6

Comment: For better answers you should also tell us about how you set the global variables. I think the culprit is there.

Comment: @Pindatjuh Your regexp does nothing else as indexOf compared to 0... If the prefix is "t_" it won't find "text_var" btw.

Comment: @christoph good point about javascript vs renderer

Comment: @Pindatjuh: Checking that `indexOf` is zero *will* ensure that it starts with the prefix.

Comment: Reconsider joining your key/value pairs by "&" without proper escaping, eg replace "&" in each value by "&amp;" first (or something other appropriate).

Comment: Despite all of the above, you do seem to have discovered a very strange oddity.

Comment: The correct escaping for URL query values would be `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known issue, IE does not expose global variables for for-in loop over window object (inspite that fact that accessing global variables directly like window.globalVar works).
The possible workaround is to declare global variables explictly as members of window object, like:

```
window.globalVar = 1;
...
alert(globalVar); // = 1
globalVar = 'xxx';
alert(window.globalVar); // = xxx
```

By declaring variables in such way in the beginning of script you'll make them accessible for for-in loop.

The better solution of course is to avoid global vars :-)
Or at least keeping all them in separate variable which you can later traverse without hacks.

Comment: Ok, in the end I will have to use something along the lines of what you proposed. By confirming that IE does things differently (now theres a suprise), I have written a little function to first check if being run in IE ...

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it should work, is global a keyword? try using something else or just the windows variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

In IE be sure to also store your properties where you want them to be upon read.

Answer (score 0):

`global` is actually *not* a [JavaScript reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words).

Try this instead of what you have (commented for potential problems your code is likely running into on IE):

```
function getGlobalProperties(prefix) {
  var keyValues = [], global = window; // window for browser environments
  for (var prop in global) {
    if (prop.indexOf(prefix) == 0) { // check the prefix
      try {
        // this implicitly converts a window property to a string, which might fail
        keyValues.push(prop + "=" + global[prop]);
      } catch (e) {
        // in case string conversion blows up
        // do something about it here
      }
    }
  }
  return keyValues.join('&'); // build the string
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question?

Comment: He didn't provide an error (if any) that IE is raising, so I'm making an assumption that something in IE's `window` object does not like being converted to a string.

Comment: I see, in actuality there is no error, I've tried it myself it lists other properties on the window object but not global variables.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: You are correct, and that was in the original question. My reading comprehension is terrible today! Should I delete my answer or do you think it adds to the conversation?